# How to change width of single column of a table?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

hello I have created table in PDF file using Itext library heading of my table columns are Medicine Name, Doses, time

My problem is:
this is how my columns look like:

```
|Medicin|Doses|time|
| e name|     |    |
```

as you can see e falls in new line I have tried many things but cant figure out how to arrange my columns like :

```
|Medicine|Doses|time|
|  name  |     |    |
```

Comment: Did you try changing the widths of the column? That's not clear from your question. The different columns already like to have a different width in your example.

Comment: there is no option to set width of column explicitly in Itext library. space is divided equally in total no of columns.

Comment: I'm the original developer of iText and the author of the iText books. I know for a fact that there's more than one way to set the width of columns in iText ;-)

Comment: ohhh... My apology. iText is awesome.. actually for whole time I was working on cell.

Comment: No problem. See the smiley I added ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ColumnWidths](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=76) example demonstrates different ways of changing the width of a column. This is one specific way:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.setWidths(new int[]{2, 1, 1});
```

Now the width of the first column is double the size of the second and third column. See [the complete example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=76) for other ways to change the widths of columns.