# Multiple Tables to PDF Report in Java using iText

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText for generating PDF file from a table data.Actually I am able to generate the PDF file with single table. But I don’t know how to generate second table in that same PDF file. When I tried to do it, second table is coming as part of the first table.

```
String date = DateUtils.getTimestamp().toString();
date = date.replace(" ", "_");
date = date.replace(":", "_");
date = "d:/CompareDeal_" + date + ".pdf" ;

Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, new FileOutputStream(date));
my_pdf_report.open();  

PdfPTable my_report_table = new PdfPTable(5); // CREATING TABLE rt
PdfPCell table_cell;
String blank_column = "";
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(blank_column));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 1 column 1

String deal1_plan="Deal1:Plan";
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal1_plan));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 1 column 2

String deal1_actual="Deal1:Actual";
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal1_actual));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 1 column 3

String deal2_plan="Deal2:Plan";
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal2_plan));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 1 column 4

String deal2_actual="Deal2:Actual";
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal2_actual));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);  // rt row 1 column 5

table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Revenue(M$)"));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 2 column 1

String planRevenue1 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getPlanRevenue1(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(planRevenue1));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 2 column 2

String actualRevenue1 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getActualRevenue1(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(actualRevenue1));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 2 column 3

String planRevenue2 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getPlanRevenue2(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(planRevenue2));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 2 column 4

String actualRevenue2 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getActualRevenue2(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(actualRevenue2));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 2 column 5

table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PPM"));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 3 column 1

String planPpm1 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.convertToUSFormat(model.getPlanPpm1(),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING);
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(planPpm1));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 3 column 2

String actualPpm1 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.convertToUSFormat(model.getActualPpm1(),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING);
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(actualPpm1));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 3 column 3

String planPpm2 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.convertToUSFormat(model.getPlanPpm2(),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING);
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(planPpm2));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 3 column 4

String actualPpm2 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.convertToUSFormat(model.getActualPpm2(),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING),StringUtils.DEFAULT_EMPTY_STRING);
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(actualPpm2));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);// rt row 3 column 5

table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rev per FTE($)"));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 4 column 1
String planFte1 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getPlanFte1(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(planFte1));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 4 column 2

String actualFte1 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getActualFte1(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(actualFte1));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 4 column 3

String planFte2 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getPlanFte2(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(planFte2));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 4 column 4

String actualFte2 = StringUtils.convertToString(StringUtils.formatForNull(model.getActualFte2(), "-", ""));
table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(actualFte2));
my_report_table.addCell(table_cell); // rt row 4 column 5

my_pdf_report.add(my_report_table); // ADDING TABLE rt
PdfPTable my_report_table1 = new PdfPTable(5); // CREATING TABLE t1
PdfPCell table_cell1;
String blank_column1 = "";
table_cell1=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(blank_column1));
my_report_table1.addCell(table_cell1); // t2 row 1 column 1

String deal1_plan1="Deal1:Plan";
table_cell1=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal1_plan1));
my_report_table1.addCell(table_cell1); // t2 row 1 column 2

String deal1_actual1="Deal1:Actual";
table_cell1=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal1_actual1));
my_report_table1.addCell(table_cell1); // t2 row 1 column 3

String deal2_plan1="Deal2:Plan";
table_cell1=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal2_plan1));
my_report_table1.addCell(table_cell1); // t2 row 1 column 4

String deal2_actual1="Deal2:Actual";
table_cell1=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(deal2_actual1));
my_report_table1.addCell(table_cell1); // t2 row 1 column 5

my_pdf_report.add(my_report_table1); // ADDING TABLE r1
my_pdf_report.close();
```

So far this is what I have done.

Is there anyway we can add styles to the table generated like Font size and font color?

Comment: Does you code work? According you source code you add two tables.

Answer (score 1):

At first I didn't understand your question. I updated your code with some comments so that I could have a better understanding of where you create, populate and add the table. I could clearly see that you add two different tables and I didn't understand why you'd claim that the second table is coming as part of the first table. You are adding *two different tables*.

However, maybe your eyes are fooling you. Maybe you only see one table because there is no extra space between the table I marked as `rt` and the table I marked as `t1`. This can easily be fixed like this:

```
PdfPTable my_report_table = new PdfPTable(5);
my_report_table.setSpacingAfter(10);
```

This will add some extra space after the table I marked with `rt`, more specifically, the distance between `rt` and `t1` will be 10 user units (which is by default about 10 pt).

Another option is to add some extra spacing before the second table:

```
PdfPTable my_report_table1 = new PdfPTable(5);
my_report_table1.setSpacingBefore(10);
```

This adds 10 user units of space before the second table.

As for your other doubt: I also have a doubt. I doubt that you have consulted the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). In this book, you'll find a chapter entitled "Tables" and another chapter entitled "Table events". In these chapters, you'll find the answer to questions such as:

- [C# iTextSharp multi fonts in a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750597/c-sharp-itextsharp-multi-fonts-in-a-single-cell)
- [How to change width of single column of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141791/how-to-change-width-of-single-coloumn-of-table-itext-android)
- [What is the PdfPTable.DefaultCell property used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006618/what-is-the-pdfptable-defaultcell-property-used-for)
- [How to use a dotted line as a cell border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117321/dotted-line-for-cell-border)
- [How to introduce rounded cells with a background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798850/how-to-introduce-rounded-cells-with-a-background-color)
- [How to set background image in PdfPCell in iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162974/how-to-set-background-image-in-pdfpcell-in-itext)
- ...

Your second question is too broad for StackOverflow. Please consult the documentation and it you don't find the answer there, post a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Space did the job for me. Is there anyway i can add a paragraph between those 2 tables ?

Comment: Of course you can add a paragraph between those 2 tables! Why don't you try this before asking the question. Also: please read the [documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). I have spent *many hours* writing the answers bundled in that book. It would be a shame if you said *I am not interested in learning more about the tool I am using.*